# Angular 2 typescript:How to show dropdown and textbox based on radio button

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

My UI contain two radio buttons YES and NO, how to show dropdown and textbox based on these radio button values. Example if user click YES radio then need to show dropdown,if user checked NO radio then textbox should show using angular 2 typescript.please anybody provide link or help me to do.

Comment: you can use *ngIf. for better solution please put some code.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315828/angular-2-how-to-clear-the-dropdown-and-textbox-values-while-switching-the-rad which is the same question with more details.

Answer (score 4):

Small changes to aholtry's answer as that will not unfortunately work. The values of the radio buttons are not `boolean`, but `string`, so the values have to be checked against string values, here I used "yes" and "no".

So:

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" value="yes" />YES
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" value="no"/>NO

<select *ngIf="radioValue == 'yes'">
    <option>Some Option</option>
</select>

<input type="text" *ngIf="radioValue == 'no'" />
```

This should get you started! :)

Comment: Thank you, but how to clear the dropdown and textbox values while switching through radio buttons.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you elaborate some more. Currently the code in my answer does clear the select and input when switching between radio buttons. But I guess you have some more code?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example without seeing your code. If you could give a code example then I can elaborate more.

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="radioValue"  name="radioValue" value="true" />YES
    <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="radioValue"  name="radioValue" value="false" />NO
</div>
<div>
    <select *ngIf="!radioValue">
        <option>Some Option</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" *ngIf="radioValue" />
</div>
```