# Angular 2 : how to clear the dropdown and textbox values while switching the radio buttons

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

UI shows two radio buttons, one is YES and one is NO, if user clicks YES radio then I am showing dropdown and if he clicks NO then showing textbox, now how to clear the dropdown and textbox values while switching between radio buttons, both textbox and dropdown showing previous values while switching.please help me.

```
<div id="radio" class="row">Are you an existing client?</p>

         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
             <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" value="yes"/>yes
             </label>
         </div>

         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" value="no"/>no
                </label>
         </div>
         </div>

      <label *ngIf="radioValue == 'yes'">Select Client</label>
             <select #select [(ngModel)]="cuurent" (change)=logDropdown(select.value) class="form-control input-group" 
                 *ngIf="radioValue == 'yes'">
                <option *ngFor="let item of list" [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
            </select>

         <div class="form-group">
            <label  *ngIf="radioValue == 'no'">Enter Client</label>  
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputsic" class="form-control input-group" *ngIf="radioValue == 'no'" />
         </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: @gunter zochbauer its different question.i need to clear the dropdown previous values when user switched  the redio buttons..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="reset()" value="yes"/>yes
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="reset()" value="no"/>no
```

```
reset() {
  this.inputsic = '';
  this.current = null;
}
```